# Best way to find multiple items in single list kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What is the best approach to find three items in single list. I tried some code and working fine. I want to know is there any better approach for efficient, memory management or anything which is good.

```
val completeEvent = events?.lastOrNull { events -> events.status == "complete" }
val activeEvent = events?.find { events -> events.status == "active" }
val futureEvent = events?.firstOrNull { events -> events.status == "future" }
```

**ApiResponse**

```
"Events": [{
            "title": "Test 1",
            "status": "complete"
        }, {
            "title": "Test 2",
            "status": "complete"
        }, {
            "title": "Test 3",
            "status": "complete",
        }, {
            "title": "Test 4",
            "status": "complete"
        }, {
            "title": "Test 5",
            "status": "complete"
        }, {
            "title": "Test 6",
            "status": "active"
        }, {
            "title": "Test 7",
            "status": "future"
        }, {
            "title": "Test 8",
            "status": "future"
        }]
```

Comment: `find` is just a synonym for `firstOrNull`. The latter is more descriptive.

Comment: The best approach will be a trade-off which depends on the length and behaviour of the list, the complexity of the comparison, the number of items you're searching for, any special cases or conditions, how much you value readability and maintainability…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code performs 3 iterations over list. You can do it using single iteration - first you group events by status then fetch (first/last)event from that map according to the status:

```kotlin
val eventsGroupped = events?.groupBy { it.status }  // Map<String, List<Event>>

val completeEvent = eventsGroupped?.get("complete")?.lastOrNull()
val activeEvent = eventsGroupped?.get("active")?.firstOrNull()
val futureEvent = eventsGroupped?.get("future")?.firstOrNull()
```

Comment: Hey @NikolaiShevchenko my above code is finding `completeEvent`is finding the last item which result is `test 5` and your code in `completeEvent` is giving me first item i.e. `test 1`.

Comment: @vivekmodi yeah, fixed